# How to offer searchable IRC logs?

Tags: linux, service, search, logging, irc

How can I offer indexed, searchable (full text search) IRC channel logs to my users?

Also nice to have would be that users logging on to the channel could get a recap of what they missed since their last logon.

Are there bots that provide this service?

We are using hybrid ircd on Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: Currently checking out http://ruby-rbot.org/ , very little dependencies to install and it has a trivial plugin architecture that may allow me to roll my own feature quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to set up a logging bot in all channels, save them to a webpage, then have a custome google search.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do too.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://moritz.faui2k3.org/en/ilbot)'s a logging bot that stores its data to MySQL database and provide a web-based search  facility.

Comment: The format of the logging and its feature set looks nice, allthough the Perl channel specific stuff is unnecessary for us. It is interesting to see that there is very little "generic" software out there for IRC bots: lots of custom little solutions that people coded up to scratch their itch.

Answer (score 0):

You might be intrested in [djangobot](http://code.google.com/p/djangobot/) , which is used in #django

since it is build with django you can store it in several database backends, like mysql, postgresql and SQLite.